# Missing libcurl.so.3 on updating tp PHP 5.2.13

Tags: php5, centos5

I am trying to update my PHP to 5.2.13 however when I tried running yum update, it gives me this dependency error.

```
php-5.2.13-jason.1.i386 from utterramblings has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: libcurl.so.3 is needed by package php-5.2.13-jason.1.i386 (utterramblings)
Error: Missing Dependency: libcurl.so.3 is needed by package php-cli-5.2.13-jason.1.i386 (utterramblings)
Error: Missing Dependency: libcurl.so.3 is needed by package php-5.2.13-jason.1.i386 (utterramblings)
```

I believe this problem has been caused by my updating libcurl some time ago (to version 7.16.4-8.el5) but I have no idea how to solve this dependency issue.

Some time ago my friend asked me regarding missing libcurl.so.3 as well on running some script. Can't say I remember what but he did say he managed to solved it (at least on his end) so I paid no attention to the libcurl.so.3 issue anymore. But now when I try to update my PHP, this problem arises again.

This however does indeed exist (and presumably what solved my friend's issue):

```
/usr/lib/libcurl.so.3
```

Any thoughts on this matter?

I'm using centOS 5.3, PHP 5.2.11 and on LightTPD.

-Regards

Answer (score 1):

The `curl-7.15.5-9.el5` package that comes with CentOS 5 provides libcurl.so.3, and so if the 7.16.4-8.el5 package does not then you will have to either downgrade your `curl` package, or you will have to rebuild the `php` package from SRPM.

Comment: The reason I upgraded curl is to use transmission. I can't downgrade it now. So does that mean I can't update my PHP anymore? What if I bypass it? Will it affect PHP, break it for example?

Comment: You'll just have to rebuild the `php` package from SRPM yourself instead of relying on others to do it for you. Look into using `mock` for this purpose.